# Unable to access windows ntfs disk parts?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I've installed Ubuntu along with Windows 8.
At first everything was great, I could use win8 or ubuntu.

Next after installing some programs on ubuntu, im now unable to access files on windows parts and the other disk parts on my hard drive!.

Here is the message i got every time i try to open it:

```
UNABLE TO ACCESS VOLUME...
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/shadispire/1AC27B5FC27B3E57: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/shadispire/1AC27B5FC27B3E57"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: ....And a few more :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you did not shutdown windows fully. It is in fast boot mode so the filesystem is not released. Boot back to windows and shut it down over command prompt (admin mode):

```
shutdown -s -t 00
```

This will shutdown windows completely making it possible to mount the windows partition.

or use the GUI supported solution:

You can also shutdown windows completely over the windows sign in the bottom-left corner

`move mouse in bottem-left corner until windows-sign appear -> right click -> shutdown or sign out -> shutdown`

**For additional background knowledge:**

You can also determine the boot type of your last boot by using windows powershell and type/more likely copy the following:

```
$boot = Get-WinEvent -ProviderName Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-boot -MaxEvents 10 | Where-Object {$_.message -like “The boot type*”}
```

and then

```
$boot| format-list
```

giving for example in my case following output:

```
TimeCreated  : 5/29/2015 2:59:15 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Kernel
Id           : 27
Message      : The boot type was 0x0.

TimeCreated  : 5/29/2015 9:25:38 AM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Kernel
Id           : 27
Message      : The boot type was 0x0.
```

Where `The boot type was 0x0.` indicates that it was a full shutdown.

Read more [here](http://www.intowindows.com/perform-full-shutdown-or-cold-boot-charms-bar-windows-8-1/)

Cheers ;)

Comment: Does this work on 8/8.1?

Comment: @user3073656 yes!

Comment: Thank you very much for you full answer, but should i do that every time I shutdown windows?

Comment: @Muhammad yes everytime you shutdown windows and want to boot to Ubuntu. Just use my graphical solution as I stated in my answer. Please mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

The system is asking you to mount it as read only and so we will do that as a temporary fix:

```
sudo mount -t "ntfs" -ro "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/shadispire/1AC27B5FC27B3E57"
```

So the drive is currently mounted as read-only, so you can't make any changes.

If you want it to be writable, you need to get back on windows and shut it down completelely, how to do that is given clearly in another answer here.